# can't start turtlebot3_simulation

Tags: simulation, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following steps on http://turtlebot3.robotis.com/en/latest/simulation.html
Got error after

export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger
roslaunch turtlebot3_fake turtlebot3_fake.launch

THe error is

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [turtlebot3_fake/turtlebot3_fake_node]: can't locate node [turtlebot3_fake_node] in package [turtlebot3_fake]

what should I do to fix it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265881/can%27t-start-turtlebot3_simulation/) by [rosbear](https://answers.ros.org/users/31086/rosbear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like those docs don't explicitly call out to source the devel workspace after you run the build.

Try `. devel/setup.bash` to setup your environment.

This is covered in the ROS Environment tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment#Create_a_ROS_Workspace

Edit: I've opened a ticket to improve the insturctions: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_wiki/issues/10

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@rosbear, Did you install the package inside your ros workspace like below?

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations.git
cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make
```

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2017-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1